# How do I use a column I created in a Spark Join? - Ambiguous Error

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have been fighting with this for a while in scala, and I can not seem to find a clear solution for it.

I have 2 dataframes:

```
val Companies = Seq(
  (8, "Yahoo"),
  (-5, "Google"),
  (12, "Microsoft"),
  (-10, "Uber")
).toDF("movement", "Company")
```

```
val LookUpTable = Seq(
  ("B", "Buy"),
  ("S", "Sell")
).toDF("Code", "Description")
```

I need to create a column in *Companies* that allows me to join the lookup table. Its a simple *case* statement that checks if the movement is negative, then sell, else buy. I then need to join on the lookup table on this newly created column.

```
val joined = Companies.as("Companies")
    .withColumn("Code",expr("CASE WHEN movement > 0 THEN 'B' ELSE 'S' END"))
    .join(LookUpTable.as("LookUpTable"), $"LookUpTable.Code" === $"Code", "left_outer")
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'Code' is ambiguous, could be: Code, LookUpTable.Code.;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.package$AttributeSeq.resolve(package.scala:259)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveChildren(LogicalPlan.scala:101)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$40.apply(Analyzer.scala:888)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$40.apply(Analyzer.scala:890)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$.withPosition(package.scala:53)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$resolve(Analyzer.scala:887)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$resolve$2.apply(Analyzer.scala:896)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$resolve$2.apply(Analyzer.scala:896)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:329)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:327)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$resolve(Analyzer.scala:896)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$9$$anonfun$applyOrElse$35.apply(Analyzer.scala:956)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$9$$anonfun$applyOrElse$35.apply(Analyzer.scala:956)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:105)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:105
```

I have tried adding the alias for Code, but that does not work:

```
val joined = Companies.as("Companies")
    .withColumn("Code",expr("CASE WHEN movement > 0 THEN 'B' ELSE 'S' END"))
    .join(LookUpTable.as("LookUpTable"), $"LookUpTable.Code" === $"Companies.Code", "left_outer")

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`Companies.Code`' given input columns: [Code, LookUpTable.Code, LookUpTable.Description, Companies.Company, Companies.movement];;
'Join LeftOuter, (Code#102625 = 'Companies.Code)
:- Project [movement#102616, Company#102617, CASE WHEN (movement#102616 > 0) THEN B ELSE S END AS Code#102629]
:  +- SubqueryAlias `Companies`
:     +- Project [_1#102613 AS movement#102616, _2#102614 AS Company#102617]
:        +- LocalRelation [_1#102613, _2#102614]
+- SubqueryAlias `LookUpTable`
   +- Project [_1#102622 AS Code#102625, _2#102623 AS Description#102626]
      +- LocalRelation [_1#102622, _2#102623]
```

The only work around that I found was to alias the newly created column, however that then creates an additional column which feels incorrect.

```
val joined = Companies.as("Companies")
    .withColumn("_Code",expr("CASE WHEN movement > 0 THEN 'B' ELSE 'S' END")).as("Code")
    .join(LookUpTable.as("LookUpTable"), $"LookUpTable.Code" === $"Code", "left_outer")


joined.show()

+--------+---------+-----+----+-----------+
|movement|  Company|_Code|Code|Description|
+--------+---------+-----+----+-----------+
|       8|    Yahoo|    B|   B|        Buy|
|       8|    Yahoo|    B|   S|       Sell|
|      -5|   Google|    S|   B|        Buy|
|      -5|   Google|    S|   S|       Sell|
|      12|Microsoft|    B|   B|        Buy|
|      12|Microsoft|    B|   S|       Sell|
|     -10|     Uber|    S|   B|        Buy|
|     -10|     Uber|    S|   S|       Sell|
+--------+---------+-----+----+-----------+
```

Is there a way to join on the newly created column without having to create a new dataframe or new column through an alias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried using Seq in Spark dataframe.

> 1.Using Seq
>   Without duplicate column

```
val joined = Companies.as("Companies")
    .withColumn("Code",expr("CASE WHEN movement > 0 THEN 'B' ELSE 'S' END"))
    .join(LookUpTable.as("LookUpTable"), Seq("Code"), "left_outer")
```

> 2. alias after withColumn but it will generate duplicate column

```
val joined = Companies.withColumn("Code",expr("CASE WHEN movement > 0 THEN 'B' ELSE 'S' END")).as("Companies")
.join(LookUpTable.as("LookUpTable"), $"LookUpTable.Code" === $"Companies.Code", "left_outer")
```

Comment: Thanks Mahesh. Does the Second Option allow me to have multiple Alias' with the same name? i.e.

````
val joined = Companies.withColumn("Code",expr("CASE WHEN movement > 0 THEN 'B' ELSE 'S' END")).as("Companies")
.withColumn("Description", expr("TRIM(Description)")).as("Companies")
.join(LookUpTable.as("LookUpTable"), $"LookUpTable.Code" === $"Companies.Code", "left_outer")
.select($"Companies.Code",$Companies.Description")
```

Comment: @Nirmie do vote up and accept the answer if it is satisfied with your requirements.

Comment: @Nirmie you just need to keep last .as("companies") not need every time to us .as("companies") so it would be like this ````
val joined = Companies.withColumn("Code",expr("CASE WHEN movement > 0 THEN 'B' ELSE 'S' END")).withColumn("Description", expr("TRIM(Description)")).as("Companies") .join(LookUpTable.as("LookUpTable"), $"LookUpTable.Code" === $"Companies.Code", "left_outer") .select($"Companies.Code",$Companies.Description")````

Answer (score 0):

Aliasing would be required if you need the columns from `two different dataframes having same name`. This is because Spark dataframe API creates a schema for the said dataframe, and in a given schema, you can never have two or more columns with same name.

This is also the reason that, in `SQL`, the `SELECT` query without aliasing works but if you were to do a `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT`, it would throw an error like - `duplicate columns`.

Answer (score 0):

Expression can be used for join:

```
val codeExpression = expr("CASE WHEN movement > 0 THEN 'B' ELSE 'S' END")
val joined = Companies.as("Companies")
  .join(LookUpTable.as("LookUpTable"), $"LookUpTable.Code" === codeExpression, "left_outer")
```

Comment: Thanks pasha701. This may work, but on our project we have over ~2000 expressions to having to create these without contention may be a little difficult.